# How to check if a user has any previous order?

Tags: 7, commerce

I am working on Drupal Commerce site. Want to know if the customer is new or old. If customer has previously ordered any item from our website we can consider him old customer else if he is ordering first time he will be considered the new customer.

How can I get these values in a custom module?

Comment: How about granting a customer a special role (= "old customer"?) when they first order any item. So that later on, in your custom module, you just check if the customer has that role? Depending on what you want to do in your custom module, you might not even need a custom module for it. ie if you can translate your custom logic in some Rules Events/Conditions/Actions, you could add an extra condition like "does user have that role". If appropriate, I'd be happy to rework this comment in an actual answer (let me now).

Answer (score 1):

Try this method. commerce_order_load_multiple will return order

```
function module_user_has_order() {
    $order = commerce_order_load_multiple(array(), array('uid' => 'user_id','status' => 'completed'));
  if(empty($order)) {
    //user has no previous order.
  }
  else {
    // user has previous order.
  }
}
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help

used it like below in my module but unable to pass any values, may be you can correct me

 function module_user_has_order() {
  $order = commerce_order_load_multiple(array(), array('uid' => $user_uid));
  if(empty($order)) {
     $form['merchant_defined_data29'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#value' => 'New Customer',
  );
  }
  else {
    $form['merchant_defined_data29'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#value' => 'Old Customer',
  );
  }

Comment: This isn't a great approach, as it doesn't do any filtering of the order list by status at all. Every shopping cart in Drupal Commerce is an order, so this would return TRUE whether the person ever actually purchased or not. Some modules use orders for other things like wish lists as well.

Comment: @RyanSzrama Can you please point me to some thing helpful? Some one referred me to use Entity Field Query.

Comment: The edited answer demonstrates how to load orders that are only marked as completed. The problem is that you may want a variety of order statuses accommodated - even pending orders have technically been completed.

Yes, I'd look into EntityFieldQuery, but I don't have any examples to point you to off the top of my head.